# Loading plist into iOS TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist, nsdictionary

I have a plist (**images.plist**) with the following contents

[image: images.plist]

As you can see, each item has a numerical key, from 0-19. Each item also has two strings (fileName and fileInfo).

I'm trying to load all of the fileName's into a TableView. Here's my attempt:

**RosterMasterViewController.h**

```
@interface RosterMasterViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *roster;

@end
```

**RosterMasterViewController.m**

```
@implementation RosterMasterViewController

@synthesize roster = _roster;

...
// This is in my 'viewDidLoad'
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"images" ofType:@"plist"];
self.roster = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];
```

And here's how I'm trying to load the fileName into the Prototype Cells.

**RosterMasterViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"imageNameCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.roster allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fileName"];
   return cell;
}
```

**NOTE**
For the record, my CellIdentifier is correct, if I set the cell.textLabel.text to be `@"HELLO!"`, then I will see "HELLO!" for each item in the NSDictionary. I'm having difficulty with the `//Configure the cell` section

Unfortunately this isn't working as I expected. I'm having difficulty since my keys are all numerical I think.

**UPDATE**

Trying to use what I've learned from the answers below, I have this:

```
// Configure the cell
NSLog(@"Key: %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]);
NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", dict);
NSString *fileName = [dict objectForKey:@"fileName"];
NSLog(@"FileName: %@", fileName);

cell.textLabel.text = fileName;
return cell;
```

But that's giving me results like:

```
2012-02-03 11:24:24.295 Roster[31754:f803] Key: 7
2012-02-03 11:24:24.295 Roster[31754:f803] Dictionary: (null)
2012-02-03 11:24:24.296 Roster[31754:f803] FileName: (null)
```

If I change this line:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
```

to:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:@"5"];
```

Then all of the cells will have the correct fileName for the 6th element. Any idea why `[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row` isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:indexPath.row];
NSString *fileName = [dict objectForKey:@"fileName"];
```

Comment: I'm expecting `self.roster = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file];` to return a dictionary with the integer keys, but I'm still not understanding how to access the fileName from each one.

Comment: Thanks, that seems like it would work, but the first line: `NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:indexPath.row];` is giving me an error: Implicit Conversion of "NSInteger" (aka int) to 'id' is disallowed with ARC. I am using ARC, can you help me figure out why I can't do that?

Comment: @ardavis ARC just won't allow you to do that, because it needs to know if it will be dealing with an object or a primitive in advance. you can use this: NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering you. `NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:@"0"];` works, returns the correct dictionary. But `NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];` is returning null. I am quite the beginner at this!

Comment: Solved it with: `NSDictionary *dict = [self.roster objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row]];` I'll mark yours as correct since it led me to the right answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Oscar, self.roster it's a NSDictionary wich have inside of him dictionaries for each numeric key.

You must first retrieve the NSDictionary for the numeric key: `NSDictionary *fileDictionary = [self.roster objectForKey:indexPath.row];`

After that you must extract your filename from this last dictionary so you must request the string for the @"fileName" key.

```
    NSString *fileName = [fileDictionary objectForKey:@"fileName"];
    cell.textLabel.text = fileName;
    return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

No sure if you solved the problem already, but below is how I solved this issue.

```
NSDictionary *dict = 
[self.allItem objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]];
```

I think the reason was `[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]` is returning number/int value.
But `objectForKey:` is expecting to receive a string value.

Hope this help.