# How do you populate a tableview with a class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, mapkit

I'm looking for a good example on how to populate a UITableView with a class that will also push data to multiple detailed view controllers. One would just be a simple "about" page, the other a mapview. Does anyone have a good example of this or know if it can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can certainly be done! Although you'll have to explain me what you mean by "pushing" data to view controllers.

- Usually, you'll have a class implementing the [UITableViewDataSource Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to supply data to a UITableView.
- Another (or the same!) class would implement the [UITableViewDelegate Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) to tell the table view how to behave and how to look.
- Make sure to go through [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html) about programming table view in iOS for an overview of the process.
- This whole delegation pattern ([discussed here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html)) is also useful to work with [MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html).

For a start, you can look into this example from the iOS Developer Library : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: by "pushing" I mean sending the information to the view controllers.

Comment: Whats the best way to populate a tableview? would a plist work?

Comment: See this [question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130259/loading-plist-into-ios-tableview) for an example on how to do this